# Querying Cassandra 4.0 secondary index returns zero results

Tags: cassandra

I have 2 c*4 nodes. And a secondary index provisioned.

```
./nodetool ring
192.168.43.10       rack1       Up     Normal  176.08 KiB      55.56%              4716404817677783992
192.168.43.11       rack1       Up     Normal  194.74 KiB      44.44%              6854338132896405748
```

```
./bin/cqlsh 192.168.43.10
```

If I query secondary index field with token(4716404817677783992) rows are correct

```
select * from x."y" where "a"='***' and token("Id")=6854338132896405748;
```

But if I query with token("Id")=6854338132896405748
result is zero, there are no exceptions in any node. Have an idea?

Secondary index implementation founds Ids and from 3rd party source and collects rows from c*

Both scenarios working on c*3

I realized that c*4 is applying CQLFilter(RowFilter:330) but c*3 not.

node1 (sends a="x:1")-> node2 -> 3rd party

3rd pary -> node2 (here adding field to response row a="total:5..")-> node1

node1 checks "a=x:1" with "a=total=5" in c*4 but no check in c*3. because of this check rows are filtered out. Any idea is this configurable? or a new security feature ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add token() to your select:

```
select a, id, token(id) from x."y" where "a"='***';
```

Might help to see what those hashed token values are, it might be different between versions.  Change that query up if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Querying by an indexed column AND a token value makes no sense at all and I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with your query.

As a matter of fact, a query with a filter on the tokenised `id` value:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE token(id)=6854338132896405748
```

makes no sense. If you already know the partition key then just use it directly in the filter:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?
```

Cassandra's partitioner will tokenise the partition key without you needing to know in advance what the token value is. Did I misunderstand your question?

As a side note, welcome to Stack Exchange! A friendly note to let you know your question is missing a few details. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) steps to replicate the problem.

In your case, you should provide:

- sample table schema
- minimal sample data for replicating the issue
- CQL query that works + sample output
- CQL query that does not work
- expected result/output
- actual result/output

Providing the right information will make it easy for others to help. If others don't understand your question, you are unlikely to get help. Cheers!